# Postgres converting double double precision to text creates '1.50000000000'

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

Working with postgres and I need to convert total minutes into the format of 1h 1m.

I'm doing this via the following code

```
replace(
    (119 / 60 + (119 % 60) / 100.0)::text, 
    '.', 
    'h '
) + 'm'
```

which returns 1h 59000000000000000000m

119 is just an example amount of minutes I've added, but this would be set on a larger query that would do

```
(accumulated_minutes / 60 + (accumulated_minutes % 60) / 100.0)::text,
```

is there a way to convert this to text without adding the extra precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the database do the heavy lifiting for you! You can turn the number of minutes to an `interval` datatype, and use `to_char()` for formating:

```
to_char(make_interval(mins => accumulated_minutes), 'hh24"h" mi"m"')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4f069838b39b0e7a899abe207139a9b1)**:

```
select to_char(make_interval(mins => 119), 'hh24"h" mi"m"') val
```

```
| val     |
| :------ |
| 01h 59m |
```

If you want to suppress the leading `0`s on hours and minutes, then:

```
to_char(make_interval(mins => accumulated_minutes), 'fmhh24"h" fmmi"m"') val
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try first casting the quotient or modulus to integer, then casting to text after that, e.g.

```
SELECT (119 / 60)::int::text || 'h ' || (119 % 60)::int::text || 'm';
```

This outputs `1h 59m`.